# SignalR - can't connect from js client to asp.net core 7 server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I have built asp.net core 7 project based on GRPC template because i need to have grpc communication in my service. The service is notification service and it's part of microservices project, so i need grpc and i added signalR for sending notifications to client. I built a basic js client to try to test my service and i am getting error connecting them, i also tried with .net web app and making js client there and react app and nothing works so it seems that problem is on server. [image: Error].
Program.cs of my service (there are probably some things that i forgot to remove while i was trying to find the solution):

```
using notification_service.Hubs;
using notification_service.messaging.Configuration;

var AllowedOriginsPolicy = "allowedOriginsPolicy";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Additional configuration is required to successfully run gRPC on macOS.
// For instructions on how to configure Kestrel and gRPC clients on macOS, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099682

// Bson congifuration
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5500", "http://localhost:5272", "http://localhost:3000")
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowCredentials();
    });
});
builder.Services.AddGrpc();
builder.Services.AddNotificationDbSettings(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.Configure<NatsConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("NatsConfiguration"));
builder.Services.Configure<NotificationNatsConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("NotificationNatsConfig"));
builder.Services.AddGrpcChannelOptions();
builder.Services.Configure<ServicesConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Services"));
builder.Services.AddAuth();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddServices();
builder.Services.AddHostedServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseWebSockets();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseCors();

app.Urls.Add($"http://localhost:{app.Configuration["NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_ADDRESS"]}" ?? "http://localhost:12009");

app.MapGet("/", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
app.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/hubs/notification");
```

Code for client:

```
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

const SinglarTest = () => {
  let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:12009/hubs/notification", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    })
    .build();

  connection.start()
    .then(() => { console.log("Connection established")})
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });

  connection.on("notification", (data) => {
    console.log('data: ', data);
  })
}

export default SinglarTest;
```

I was searching for solution for long time and tried many different things (activated web sockets from windows features, removed my authorization and copied solution from microsoft docs, tried different options on client...) but nothing helps.

Comment: The problem was i started from .grpc project template and it configured http2 as default for endpoints.

Comment: Comment this line `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` in your Program.cs file.  Or using `https` in your front-end. Please let me know this is useful to you or not.

Comment: Yea I removed it now because I don't need it but the problem was that http2 was default for endpoints.

Comment: let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("http://localhost:12009/hubs/notification", {
      skipNegotiation: true,
      transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets
    }).configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug).build();

Comment: Using this and share the debug details.

Comment: So this question can be closed, i said the problem was that i started from grpc project template which has http2 as default protocol in appsettings so i just changed it to http1 because i don't even need it to be grpc i just need the grpc client to communicate with auth service via grpc, so it was my bad to start from grpc project template.